# What mechanism can we use to convert waves energy?

Tags: energy, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, renewable-energy

In term of renewable energy, can we use waves as another energy that can be stored and used instead of solar, wind and etc ? What I mean here is not sea waves but another kind of waves such as radio wave. Maybe energy stored in that wave could be converted to another energy which can provide electricity. If could, then how it could be converted?

Comment: For radio waves it is called an antenna.

Comment: This is called [Energy Harvesting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_harvesting#Ambient-radiation_sources) - but harvesting energy from other businesses' communications systems causes them problems and stealing energy is usually a crime.

Comment: Kind of related: [superconducting magnetic energy storage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superconducting_magnetic_energy_storage) (SMES), which stores energy in a magnetic field, rather than in a propagating electromagnetic wave.

Answer (score 1):

Of course the answer is that you could try to do this.  The question that is more interesting is whether it's a good idea.  The answer to the latter question, is probably "no" in most cases.  Unless you come up with something super fancy, the losses that you have in trying to maintain the wave will be greater than the losses that you get in more traditional storage systems. (If you do have this "super fancy" idea, then you can probably make a ton of money on it - People are always looking for more efficient storage.)

The mechanism for converting to/from the wave and the modes of loss will depend a lot on what type of wave.  You left this wide open.  For the "radio wave" that you explicitly mentioned, as noted in a comment, an antenna is the basic tool for creating / receiving electromagnetic wave energy.  You could presumable create a resonance chamber that would hold such a wave (with losses over time).